# Two different nodes giving same call to same MYSQL Database giving different responses

Tags: mysql, node.js, api-design

I have my first NodeJS API running.  I have two API's now running (TEST and PROD).
These files are DIRECT copies of each other and running via App Manager in Cpanel.

Weirdly, one of the calls (Prod) is giving incorrect information on some of the calls... like it is giving 'old' data.

eg. a record was changed for an 'order' and a locationID was added to the database.

I have checked the database and it was added.

The test call:

```
https://www.myAPI.com.au/TEST/orders/myOrders/1709
```

Response:

```
{
    "Result": true,
    "order": {
        "orderID": 1709,
        "chemOrderID": 1243,
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "phone": "04123456",
        "email": null,
        "prefContact": 1,
        "itemName": "KN95 Box Of 30 ",
        "itemQuantity": 1,
        "plu": null,
        "modelNumber": null,
        "colour": null,
        "itemDetails": null,
        "supplier": "avacare",
        "itemSize": null,
        "amountPaid": 0,
        "receiptNumber": "00",
        "quotedPrice": 69.99,
        "orderComments": null,
        "reorder": 0,
        "isNDIS": 0,
        "isNDISPaid": 0,
        "onHold": 0,
        "requestedBy": 35,
        "orderedBy": 35,
        "receivedBy": 35,
        "finalisedBy": 0,
        "overdueBy": 0,
        "NDISBy": 0,
        "deletedBy": 0,
        "requestedByName": "Jac",
        "orderedByName": "Jac",
        "receivedByName": "Jac",
        "finalisedByName": null,
        "overdueByName": null,
        "deletedByName": null,
        "requestedDateShort": "18 Jan",
        "orderedDateShort": "18 Jan",
        "receivedDateShort": "18 Jan",
        "finalisedDateShort": null,
        "overdueDateShort": null,
        "deletedDateShort": null,
        "requestedDate": "2022-01-18T09:40:21",
        "orderedDate": "2022-01-18T09:50:33",
        "receivedDate": "2022-01-18T12:21:41",
        "finalisedDate": null,
        "overdueDate": null,
        "deletedDate": null,
        "etaMaxDateShort": "Thu, 20 Jan",
        "etaCode": 2,
        "locationID": 199,
        "supplierRef": null,
        "locationOther": null,
        "categoryID": 5,
        "categoryName": "GENERAL SHOP"
    }
}
```

Now this is correct.  The locationID is updated, the receivedDate, recivedByName and receivedBy are all correct and updated.

The same call on copied API: (same mysql user login. literally a duplicate of the api)

Call:

```
https://www.myAPI.com.au/prod/orders/myOrders/1709
```

Response:

```
{
    "Result": true,
    "order": {
        "orderID": 1709,
        "chemOrderID": 1243,
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test",
        "phone": "04123456",
        "email": null,
        "prefContact": 1,
        "itemName": "KN95 Box Of 30 ",
        "itemQuantity": 1,
        "plu": null,
        "modelNumber": null,
        "colour": null,
        "itemDetails": null,
        "supplier": "avacare",
        "itemSize": null,
        "amountPaid": 0,
        "receiptNumber": "00",
        "quotedPrice": 69.99,
        "orderComments": null,
        "reorder": 0,
        "isNDIS": 0,
        "isNDISPaid": 0,
        "onHold": 0,
        "requestedBy": 35,
        "orderedBy": 35,
        "receivedBy": 0,
        "finalisedBy": 0,
        "overdueBy": 0,
        "NDISBy": 0,
        "deletedBy": 0,
        "requestedByName": "Jac",
        "orderedByName": "Jac",
        "receivedByName": null,
        "finalisedByName": null,
        "overdueByName": null,
        "deletedByName": null,
        "requestedDateShort": "18 Jan",
        "orderedDateShort": "18 Jan",
        "receivedDateShort": null,
        "finalisedDateShort": null,
        "overdueDateShort": null,
        "deletedDateShort": null,
        "requestedDate": "2022-01-18T09:40:21",
        "orderedDate": "2022-01-18T09:50:33",
        "receivedDate": null,
        "finalisedDate": null,
        "overdueDate": null,
        "deletedDate": null,
        "etaMaxDateShort": "Thu, 20 Jan",
        "etaCode": 2,
        "locationID": null,
        "supplierRef": null,
        "locationOther": null,
        "categoryID": 5,
        "categoryName": "GENERAL SHOP"
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the aforementioned fields aren't filled!?

It's like the call is getting an old version of the database or something...

I can't understand this at all.
There is only one DB, i haven't created a test db, in reality this whole thing is testing (even the prod version), as I am learning and trying to understand how I will go about everything once it is actually live.

Comment: Is this an issue with how you handle your sessions?

Comment: Hi @BGPHiJACK thanks for the response, but I'm not sure what you mean.  It is using a connection pool which should be releasing connections back and thus letting the system update correctly?